# Replacement of $.uaMatch in 1.10.2 Jquery release

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are using the $.uaMatch function which is available with JQuery 1.7.x version. Now post migrating to 1.10.2 version of JQuery we don't see this function defined.

Is there an alternative defined for the same? Could anyone assist regarding this.

http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.8.0/jQuery.uaMatch -- Link to the function.

Comment: You should use feature detection instead, not browser one.

Comment: If you really need it, is there any problem with you just adding it yourself?

Comment: Instead of looking for the non-existent function, figure out why you needed it in the first place. You likely don't need it anymore or can get by without it using other methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jquery [migrate](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin) plugin. It allows to bring features back from older versions.

example from [repo](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

Check [core.js file, line 50](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/e6bda6a84c294eb1319fceb48c09f51042c80892/src/core.js):

```
jQuery.uaMatch = function( ua ) {
  ua = ua.toLowerCase();

  var match = /(chrome)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
    /(webkit)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
    /(opera)(?:.*version|)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
    /(msie) ([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
    ua.indexOf("compatible") < 0 && /(mozilla)(?:.*? rv:([\w.]+)|)/.exec( ua ) ||
    [];

  return {
    browser: match[ 1 ] || "",
    version: match[ 2 ] || "0"
  };
};
```